# How to remove loading time between images from firebase in carousel slider in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am viewing images from firebase in a carousel slider in flutter. But there is a small loading gap everytime I swipe to the next image.

Is it possible to save the images in some way to remove the loading time between the images?

Here is my code:

```
class ViewImages extends StatelessWidget {
  
  Future getCarouselWidget() async {
        var firestore = Firestore.instance;
        QuerySnapshot qn = await firestore.collection("images").getDocuments();
        return qn.documents;
      }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var idx = 1;
    return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder(
          future: getCarouselWidget(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            List<NetworkImage> list = new List<NetworkImage>();
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return new CircularProgressIndicator(); 
            } else {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return new Text("fetch error");
              } else {

                //Create for loop and store the urls in the list 
                for(int i = 0; i < snapshot.data[0].data.length; i++ ) {
                  debugPrint("Index is " + idx.toString());
                  list.add(NetworkImage(snapshot.data[0].data["img_"+idx.toString()]));
                  idx++;
                }
                return new Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: new Carousel(
                      boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
                      images: list,
                      autoplay: false,
                      autoplayDuration: Duration(seconds: 5),
                      dotSize: 4.0,
                      indicatorBgPadding: 16.0,
                      animationCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                      animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
            dotIncreasedColor: Colors.white,
            dotColor: Colors.grey,
            dotBgColor: Colors.transparent,
            
                    ));
              }
            }
          }),
    );
  }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is [CachedNetworkImage](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image), CachedNetworkImage, as the name suggests will only fetch the image once and the cache it, so the next time you build the widget, It won't be called again.

Comment: Okay, is it possible to use this without knowing the image url? Sometimes the images will be replaced and then the url will also change.

Comment: ah, no. That won't be possible, it takes an `imageUrl` parameter. To avoid this conflict don't hardCode the `imageUrl` you can dynamically fetch and parse it from firebase. This should not be a problem since the imageUrl will be changed in the database too.  The new imageUrl will be fetched and cached again. Just Replace `ChchedNetworkImage` with `NetworkImage`